# Period of Precession

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, homework-and-exercises, precession

I'm trying to find the period of precession for a gyroscope. Now I was able to find the angular precession rate, which was 1.132 rad/s, but I have no idea how to convert this to a 'period', and google didnt find me anything useful. How do I do this?

Comment: Quick advice: add units when you write numbers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rate is $\omega_p$ given in rad/s then the period is $\frac{2 \pi}{\omega_p}$ with units of seconds.

Comment: Ya I was able to get the same thing from wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.132+radians/second thanks though!

Comment: @Cedric: This is of course correct, but we do not recommend here that direct answers be given to homework questions. Hints (to some level) are always preferred.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I first tried to answer explaining frequency, period and angular frequency, but my explanation was not clear at all.

Comment: This is barely a homework question. Just a matter of units is all

Comment: @Cedric: No worries, it's sometimes hard to hint at straightforward questions.
@fprime: It's just that when it's a relatively straightforward thing, I feel it's best to get the poster thinking about how to approach the problem if they didn't have someone around to help. :) It's a tad more than units, but not much.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Angular velocity is related to angular frequency by a constant factor. Period and frequency also have a simple (inverse) relation. Combine the two.